# Pass data via fragments alternative methods?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

We can pass data to other fragments using a)**set argument** and 2) via **constructor** . Is there any other method other than these  two method mentioned above ?

Comment: Why would you want to use other methods?

Comment: never, ever via constructor!!!

Comment: 1. Via custom static class,methods,variables.
2. Via parent activities static variable.

Comment: using set argument method we will be able to pass only string values right ? what if we need to pass a model or an arraylist of object ?

Comment: static class,methods,variables <= no .... direct via direct access through it references

Comment: *using set argument method we will be able to pass only string values right ?* huh? where in th documentation is written that you can only pass string there?

Comment: thnks @selvin for pointing it out. Yes we  can pass arraylist of string using Bundled object .But then how about passing an arraylist of object.

Comment: I'm a fan of ContentProvider ... so for me there is no problem ... as I always use Uri ... IMHO passing large data objects (like ArrayList of some POJO) is really bad idea on Android .... just send to next fragment/activity data needed for creation of the arraylist(or better cursor)

Comment: @Selvin ok but Why can't we use constructor to pass data among fragments?how does this harm my android app

Comment: becuase Fragment contructor had to be parameterless ... why? because it may be called internally by android framework ... and framework doesn't know what parameters should pass ... that's why there is setArguments method ...

Comment: I   created a method like this and passing an object of model                              
 ResponseModel model = (ResponseModel) responseModel;            changeFragment(new AbcFragment(model)); and in the fragment  i have fetched the model object in this way                  public AbcFragment() {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

 }

 public AbcFragment(ResponseModel model) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  this.model = model;// here i am getting the model
 }  Is there any problem using  this kind of fragment communication @Selvin??

Comment: yes .... orientation change will cause the NPE ... `this.model` will be never setted when framework will use `public AbcFragment()` for Fragment recreation ... if you really wana pass it "via constructor" use `setArguments` and make `ResponseModel` serializable or better `Parcelable`

Comment: ok thanks a lot! @Selvin :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the activity to implement an interface of the fragment to retrieve some data :
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html